# Reset formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I would like to reset a Formik form after it has been submitted so that the same form can be reused. I have seen various responses that clear the input with resetForm() but I would like to return the form to the same state that it was in before the first use. I see a number of methods on the form properties like resetForm and setTouched. So far I have been unable to reset the form to a 'prisitine' state. The main indicator is that the submit button is not greyed out as it should be since the second time around I would like the form to be completely cleared. It seems the field values are cleared with resetForm but there is something else that needs to be set to get the form in its original 'pristine' state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a state with your initial values and set formik values to it after submitting the form.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. In the 'onSubmit' handler there are two arguments. One, an object describing the values of the form. Two, an object that seems like it is a grab bag of Formik methods. One of those methods is resetForm. So I call 'formsProps.resetForm({file: null})' (where 'file' is the only field in the form. It indeed clears the 'file' form field bug the submit button which is controlled by Formik is still enabled (Disabled because of validation via validationSchema prop?) There is a setTouched method. But setting 'formsProps.setTouched(false) also doesn't clear validation.

Comment: You can clear fields one by one with setFieldValue() and clear validation errors with setFieldError()

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me either. Maybe it is because I am trying to set these values in the onSubmit handler?

Comment: Create a variabale with useState and put in in the dependency of useEffect. In the formik onSubmit change that state and in useEffect set formik values.